# How to avoid undefined reference when linking objects in cyclic dependencies in Gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, silverfrost-fortran

If one file has two subroutines TEST1 (calling TEST3) and TEST2, and another file with subroutines TEST3 (calling TEST2) and TEST4 (calling TEST1), then the linker will complain about undefined references, no matter what the order will be, in Gfortran, when linking.

In Silverfrost fortran (ftn95) the order is not important.
Is there a workaround in Gfortran, as it will fail to link an otherwise valid set of objects? If I put

EXTERNAL TEST3

in TEST1, and similar with the others, will that fix the issue?
Moving subroutines to the same file would make the whole source code very cumbersome.

Comment: This should be a property of the compiler. GCC uses ld for linking. However, the situation isunclear for me. Please do not explain code in sentences, show it.

Comment: Well, the obvious answer is that the programmer should avoid the circular dependency.  What stops you from place each subroutine into its own file and compiling those files in an appropriate order?

Comment: Isn’t this what interfaces are supposed to allow you to circumvent?

Comment: Instead of solving this problem, refactor the code so that the dependencies are hierarchical.  Circular dependencies normally end up in double or triple builds

Comment: I have now put all file names into a file with #include "file1.f90" #include "file2.90" and so on and there are much fewer undefined now but there are still some, depending on the order! I thought the order of the subroutines in a single file didn't matter?