# Why Gfortran fails to compile large file without any warning or errors

Tags: gfortran

I have a code with 400k lines and various modules. I had put everything in a single file due to cyclic dependencies that did not allow me to leave it in separate files (by the way the code compiles absolutely fine with Silverfrost FTn95).
When compiling it just exits after a couple of minutes or so. If I remove some files I can compile it (but fails later dependencies when linking, so not an option).

How can I force Gfortran to give an output each time a module/subroutine/function is successfully compiled? So I can get an idea of where it's failing (as there is no error as such, just no .o created).

Comment: You can't.  It seems to me that you need to compile your code with the options `-Wall -Wextra -Wsurprising -fmax-errors=1` and fix the issues as they are diagnosed.  Is there a github repository with the code so that someone that knows what they are doing with gfortran might be able to help you?

Comment: BTW, if you haven't resolved the circular dependencies, then how is this issue different from your (previous post)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78172013]?

Comment: You cannot resolve circular dependencies by putting everything into a single file. That does not fix them.

Comment: This is a different question from the previous one - it's a question how can gfortran exit a compilation without a warning or error and without producing an object file.

Comment: What I meant are circular dependencies between files - but if all subroutines are put in a single file then there are no more circular dependencies as all needed subroutines are in that file. Unless of course the order in which they appear matters - but I am thinking this is not a problem?

Comment: What OS? What version of gfortran? What stacksize?  Did you try the options I gave earlier?

Comment: Windows 10, gcc 13.1.0 64bit. I noticed that it happens also with small files if they use modules that are not up to date.  So basically it is not safe to do single compilations outside of makefile (with dependencies). So now I know that if I compile a file and there no object file created but also no error, then it's most likely the case that another file it depends on needs to be recompiled.